# numpy array giving decimals output

Tags: numpy

I am trying to create a numpy array from like `ones`, `x` and `X2` but the code below is giving me decimal points.

```
x = [10, 23, 25, 30, 37, 40, 46, 52, 60, 65]
y = [22, 46, 48, 62, 75, 90, 100, 110, 180, 150]

xx = np.array([float(v) for v in x])
yy = np.array([float(v) for v in y])
X2 = xx ** 2

ones = np.ones(len(x))

Xq = np.c_[ones,xx, X2]
Y = np.array(y).reshape(len(y),1)

print(Xq)
```

My output is:

```
[[ 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+01 1.00000000e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 2.30000000e+01 5.29000000e+02]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 2.50000000e+01 6.25000000e+02]]
```

But I want it as ints.

Comment: Please state exactly what you are unhappy with. And write out what result you would like instead.

Comment: I am getting below output :- 
[[  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+02]
 [  1.00000000e+00   2.30000000e+01   5.29000000e+02]
 [  1.00000000e+00   2.50000000e+01   6.25000000e+02]


but need output like :
1 10 100
1   x and x2

Comment: Then do not use floats. `xx=np.array(x)` and `ones = np.ones_like(xx)`

Comment: x = [10,23,25,30,37,40,46,52,60,65]
y = [22,46,48,62,75,90,100,110,180,150]
xx = np.array(x)
yy = np.array(y)
X2 = xx ** 2
ones = np.ones_like(len(x))
Xq = np.c_[ones,xx, X2]
Y = np.array(y).reshape(len(y),1)
print(Xq)
giving error :- 
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: `ones_like(xx)`, not `ones_like(len(x))`

Comment: Thanks @Paul Panzer...!!! Yes that resolves my issue.